# What are cables/boxes called for listening in on a RJ45 cable?

Tags: networking, hardware, wireshark, packet-capture, packet-sniffer

I would like to capture the traffic from a router, so I assume there must exist a cable or hardware box with 3 RJ45 socks, where two of them are IN and OUT, and the third is for capturing device (a Linux host in my case).

What are such cables/boxes called?

Comment: It's called a network tap - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_tap

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at the [Hak5 Throwing Star Lan Tap](http://hakshop.myshopify.com/products/throwing-star-lan-tap). It has features such as downgrading Gigabit to 100mbit, passive tapping and generally being hard to detect.

Comment: ..and yes, I realize that I did not really answer the question about what they are called. 'network tap' as @joeqwerty commented.

Comment: I'd assume that you could watch impedance to detect one of these on the network.

Comment: Except that the impedance would change as temperature changes? Perhaps if you had really high resolution data on impedance over a certain wire over time you could detect anomalies?

Answer (score 4):

Your best bet is probably a switch that supports port mirroring plus a box plugged in running wireshark.

This feature used to be only available on high-end, fully-managed switches, but now $60 gets you entry.

http://www.netgear.com/business/products/switches/prosafe-plus-switches/gs105e.aspx

Comment: When you can afford downtime, choose Netgear!

Comment: This is not critical infrastructure. This is a tap. Netgear is fine, particularly since the other answer posted is a passive device that forces a drop to 100Mbit/s.  If you're looking for uptime then you want a device acting as a bridge with a bypass adapter.

Comment: This is a much better solution.  The tap referenced is uni-directional (as many such devices are), meaning you only get one direction on each of the monitoring ports.  However you really want devices that can mirror ports natively for a business network.  Connecting an inline device requires downtime of the link and adds an unnecessary point of failure; neither of which is really acceptable when easily avoided with proper design.

Answer (score -1):

they are called sniffers. there are wifi and cable sniffers. ten years ago the range of sniffers to connect to a lan via rj45 ran from $500 to $5000+ a good wifi sniffer or cable will set you back a pretty penny. then when the transmission is scrambled, you need more software and a super computer to decipher the message. but plain text can be captured and sometimes recorded with a low budget sniffer. there are other software tools for monitoring network traffic which are available.